# How should I arrange these modal verbs?

Tags: sentence-structure

I have a question about sentence structure.  I found a sentence like this,

> Wenn Sie es wissen muessen, so erkläre ich Ihnen, dass ich einen Besuch gehabt habe.

My question is about the first clause.  If I were to write

"You must know it", I would say "Sie müssen es wissen".  Why then does it become "wissen müssen" when I say "If you must know it ..." ?

Comment: "Besuch" is not usually used with an indefinite article in German. You'd just drop the article: "...dass ich Besuch gehabt habe."

Comment: The main clause is "so erkläre ich Ihnen [object]. Just because it is the first clause that doesn't make the knowing part the main clause.

Comment: @elena That's just what the book said.  It's from Assimil.  I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Wenn" is a subordinating conjunction like "weil" and "dass" and hence the verb needs to be placed at the end when this is used.

> Wenn ich genug Geld hätte, dann...

Comment: But the second half of the sentence also begins with a subordinating conjunction (dass), so I'm confused.

Comment: You can have two subordinating conjunctions in a sentence. If you wanted to say "if I had known, that I had enough money" that would also be a similar construct "wenn ich gewusst hätte, dass ich genug Geld hatte". Hope that helps.

Comment: @KorganRivera The Sentence structure here is `[Subclause 1 Level A, Main Clause, Subclause 2 Level A]` Both subclauses reference the main clause `so erkläre ich Ihnen`. The example in user5105's comment has the structure `[Subclause Level A, Subclause Level B, Main clause (missing)]`. The second subclause `dass ich genug Geld hatte` is referencing the first subclause instead of the main clause.

Answer (score 1):

To begin I will point out that your original sentence isn't a full sentence (right now it roughly translates to "If you must know that I've had a visit.") But the entirety of the sentence isn't in question.

It's

> Wenn Sie es wissen müssen

because *wenn* is a [subordinating conjunction](http://marathonsprachen.com/german-subordinating-conjunctions-yes-sometimes-the-verb-goes-at-the-end/) which means that all verbs in the clause following *wenn* come at the end (if there's more than 1 they come in reverse order from how they'd normally appear.

> Wenn er ankommt, gehen wir heim (normal: Er kommt an)
>
> Wenn Sie das wirklich wissen wollen... (normal: Sie wollen das wirklich wissen)
>
> Wenn du das Haus bauen lassen willst... (normal: Du willst das Haus bauen lassen)

Comment: You're right: I missed out part of that sentence.  I have corrected it.